# HTMlUnit - getByXPath - Get Values Back From Attribute List

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to get just the value from an xpath query for hrefs attributes but I can't figure out how to state the query, at best I get my refs back in a list of DomAttr that I need to use getValue() on to get the actual link.

My very simple set-up is the following:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(siteRef);
var hrefs = page.getByXPath("//@href"); // Returns a list of DomAttr
```

E: This returns the value but it also only returns the first element it finds

```
var hrefs = page.getByXPath("string(//@href)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are right, there is no way to get an array (or `List`) of `String` from `getByXPath` values.

Nevertheless, you can achieve that behavior by utilizing java streams. There you benefit from additional possibilities to work with that result list (e.g. filter it or use additional processing like `toLowerCase` on `String`s):

```
var hrefs = page.getByXPath("//@href")
                .stream()
                .filter(o -> o instanceof DomAttr) //to be sure you have the correct type
                .map(o -> ((DomAttr) o)) //cast the stream from Object to DomAttr
                .map(DomAttr::getValue) //get value of every DomAttr
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect it to a list
```

`hrefs` now contains a `List<String>`.

Instead of `collect`ing the results in last step you can further work with the stream.

Comment: Ah, smart! Didn't think I could turn it into a stream, more elegant solution to the issue than I had. Thanks! I will accept it as an offer :)